# Activeadmin 1.3.2 issues in rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using the active admin gem into my new project with Ruby 2.5.1p57 and Rails 5.2.1. All are good. But, I am facing the issue with open new resource link or update the resource. Even, If I add permit_params, same issue.

```
Started GET "/admin/admin_users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-04 20:59:08 +0530
Processing by Admin::AdminUsersController#new as HTML
AdminUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `admin_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
↳ /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@regroup2/bundler/gems/activeadmin- 
c301ab126b3f/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:39
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
```

Answer (score 0):

But finally, Fixed the issue by adding below line code to the following 
file:

`config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
def resource_params
[(params[resource_request_name] || params[resource_instance_name]).try(:permit!) || {}]
end
```

Not sure. Is this correct way to do.